# @Font-face in CSS file not working despite no reported error

Tags: html, css, fonts

I guess this is a common problem but after reading through several threads I wasn't able to fox the problem. So:

I'm developing a website and am currently using it on my local machine (without any webserver, just my IDE). My folder structure would look like this:

```
|
|
 ---fonts
|    |
|     ---Raleway-Regular.ttf
|
 ----css
|    |
|     ---default.css
|
 --- main.html
```

I'm including the font in my css file like that:

```
@font-face {
font-family: Raleway, sans-serif;
src: url("../fonts/Raleway-Regular.ttf") format("truetype");
}

@font-face {
font-family: Raleway, sans-serif;
font-weight: bold;
src: url("../fonts/Raleway-Bold.ttf") format("truetype");
}
```

and using them in my class:

```
.l-menu-group {
display: inline-block;
float: right;
height: 100%;
margin-right: 40px;
color: #505050;
font-family: Raleway, sans-serif;
text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

I'm using Opera and the network/browser console did not report any errors (no 404 etc.), also visiting at localhost:port/Project/fonts/Raleway-Regular.ttf resulted in downloading the font and thus worked. I've emptied my cache, everything without success.

**Edit**: Just using Google Fonts links did the job but I still would like to have all files local to the server.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: What do you mean "I'm not using a server"? Are you loading from `file:///`? If so, you *need* to run a server for this to work. If not, and you're seeing `http://` then you *are* using a server, and mentioning which IDE you're in and what you're using to effect the hosting is a great idea. Also important: try more browsers. See what you get in the console and network tabs in Firefox or Chrome for this content.

Comment: IDE is Intellij IDEA, I'm viewing the HTML docs through the HTTP protocol (don't know how the IDE works under the covers - internal file server?). Regarding the server part: When in previous Java projects I was using a "real" server, e.g. Tomcat or Glassfish, I didn't encounter a problem with fonts using the very same syntax. Firefox also didn't reveal any errors.

Comment: what happens when you don't use intelliJ but use a python/php/node/etc simple server? If that works fine, then we know the problem is intelliJ

Comment: AFAIK class names must not start with a digit...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When specifying fonts with `@font-face`, your `font-family` descriptor must be *only* the font name, like so:

```
font-family: "Raleway";
```

whereas you have included `sans-serif`, which is invalid.

Comment: simple but easy to miss, Thanks :)